# Where can I define the default i18n language in JHipster?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I am new to JHipster and I would like to where can I define the default i18n language in JHipster? Is it in a Java Configuration class, in Spring-Boot yaml file, or in Javascript file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the newer version of Jhipster (v 3.0.0 - the one I've been using), you will need to change two places:

- `src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/translation.config.js`: change the line `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');` with your preferred language key (e.g. `'en'` -> `'fr'`);
- `src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/translation-storage.provider.js`: change the line `$cookies.putObject(name, 'en');` with your preferred language key as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the language you like in the `weapp/scripts/app.js` file by changing the preferred language line, for instance `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr');`changes the language to french.

Comment: Take in account that the preferred language is saved as a cookie, so you have to clean that cookie for provider config to work

Answer (score 6):

And for JHipster 5.7.2 it's in `src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts` under `defaultI18nLang`.

Answer (score 3):

For jhipster: 4.12.0

Angular: 5

It's in this file: **src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared-libs.module.ts** under the property **"defaultI18nLang"**

Answer (score 1):

And for JHipster 7.2.0 it's in src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts under:

```
translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
// if user have changed language and navigates away from the application and back to the application then use previously choosed language;
const langKey = sessionStorageService.retrieve('locale') ?? 'en';
```

Answer (score 0):

For jhipster 6.5.1 you should edit `defaultI18nLang` in `/src/main/webapp/app/core/core.module.ts`, for example `defaultI18nLang: 'ar-ly'`